# Intercepting queries oracle database 11g (e-business suite)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apps

I want to know which **tables** the oracle application is using in order to obtain the contact information for a certain customer.

So, i go to the application (html page),i put my username and password. Then, i write the account number and click on "go". Take a look at the picture:
[image: ju]

After that, i click on the "communication" button and the contact information appears.

Take a look:

[image: ju]

How can i know which tables are used when i click on "go" for that account number?

A friend of mine told me that TOAD was a great tool but i dont know how to use it. Is it free? What query should i use?

Can you help me? I am a little confused :/

Comment: Toad is not free. If you want a free tool check out [Oracle SQL Developer(https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html). However, if you really want to understand what an Apps module does the best approach would be to open the source in Oracle Forms Builder.

Comment: @APC Thank you for replying!. My friend is willing to help me, he will let me to use his version. Have you got any idea how can i use TOAD in order to obtain the tables?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query to get the contact information for a Customer at Party and Party Site levels.

```
SELECT DISTINCT hp.party_id, 
                   hp.party_name,
                   hca.cust_account_id,
                   hca.account_number,
                   party_site_id,
                   party_site_number,
                   hcp.phone_number,
                   NVL (hcp.email_address, hcp.url) email_or_url,
                   hcp.contact_point_type communication_type,
                   hcp.status active,
                   hcp.contact_point_purpose purpose
     FROM apps.hz_contact_points hcp,
          apps.hz_party_sites hps,
          apps.hz_cust_accounts hca,
          apps.hz_parties hp
    WHERE     hps.party_id = hca.party_id
          AND hp.party_id = hca.party_id
          AND hcp.contact_point_type IN ('PHONE','EMAIL') 
          AND hcp.owner_table_name = 'HZ_PARTIES'
          AND hcp.owner_table_id = hps.party_id
          AND hcp.status = 'A'
          AND hps.status = 'A'
          AND hca.status = 'A'
          AND hp.status = 'A'
   UNION
   SELECT DISTINCT hp.party_id, 
                   hp.party_name,
                   hca.cust_account_id,
                   hca.account_number,
                   party_site_id,
                   party_site_number,
                   hcp.phone_number,
                   NVL (hcp.email_address, hcp.url) email_or_url,
                   hcp.contact_point_type communication_type,
                   hcp.status active,
                   hcp.contact_point_purpose purpose
     FROM apps.hz_contact_points hcp,
          apps.hz_party_sites hps,
          apps.hz_cust_accounts hca,
          apps.hz_parties hp
    WHERE     hps.party_id = hca.party_id
          AND hp.party_id = hca.party_id
          AND hcp.contact_point_type IN ('PHONE','EMAIL') 
          AND hcp.owner_table_name = 'HZ_PARTY_SITES'
          AND hcp.owner_table_id = hps.party_site_id
          AND hcp.status = 'A'
          AND hps.status = 'A'
          AND hp.status = 'A'
          AND hca.status = 'A';
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered already in thread: [Trying to know which tables are executed in the oracle external application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54075616/trying-to-know-which-tables-are-executed-in-the-oracle-external-application/54080237?noredirect=1#comment94994194_54080237)

You would need to look in v$sqlarea or if the SQLs execute slowly enough, you will find them in v$active_session_history. To retrieve the EBS specific user and responsibility information, you can use our [active session history Blitz Report](https://www.enginatics.com/reports/dba-awr-active-session-history/).