# Trying to know which tables are executed in the oracle external application

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apps

I wonder if this could be possible or not.

I am using TOAD, connected to an oracle database (11g) and i have access to the oracle E-BUSINESS-SUITE application.

**Basically, i want Toad to trace what sql are being executed by the oracle E-BUSINESS-SUITE application**

I have this query:

```
SELECT nvl(ses.username,'ORACLE PROC')||' ('||ses.sid||')' USERNAME,
       SID,   
       MACHINE, 
       REPLACE(SQL.SQL_TEXT,CHR(10),'') STMT, 
      ltrim(to_char(floor(SES.LAST_CALL_ET/3600), '09')) || ':'
       || ltrim(to_char(floor(mod(SES.LAST_CALL_ET, 3600)/60), '09')) || ':'
       || ltrim(to_char(mod(SES.LAST_CALL_ET, 60), '09'))    RUNT 
  FROM V$SESSION SES,   
       V$SQLtext_with_newlines SQL 
 where SES.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
   and SES.USERNAME is not null
   and SES.SQL_ADDRESS    = SQL.ADDRESS 
   and SES.SQL_HASH_VALUE = SQL.HASH_VALUE 
   and Ses.AUDSID <> userenv('SESSIONID') 
 order by runt desc, 1,sql.piece
```

The oracle application looks like this:

[image: ju]

[image: yu]

I want to do this because i want to know which **tables** the oracle application is using in order to obtain the contact information for a certain customer. I mean, when a random guy is using the application, he put the account_number and click on "go". Thats what i need!, i want to know which tables are executed when the guy pressed the "go" button, i want to trace that.

I think that i could get the session_id from the guy that is using the oracle application and then, paste it on the query written above and start working on it.

Something like this:

[image: kiu]

If it is possible, how could i get the session_id from the guy that is using the oracle E-BUSINESS-SUITE Application?

Comment: 'from the guy' - why not just do it for your own session? login to ebiz, then use your tool to figure out what your SID is, and then enable a session trace. You'll need access to the server where the trace files live. OR you could skip all this and just go dive into the ebiz schema and look for tables/columns that look like they might store your data

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Thank you for replying. Okay,i will use my own credentials.
I dont fully understand this: "You'll need access to the server where the trace files live" can you help me with this?
PS: i have no any schema, i need to do this :(

Comment: You said: " login to ebiz". Do you mean connecting to the database using TOAD?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I have this:
https://imgur.com/a/E9ADBGr

Comment: you're using the oci scanner tool quest has that will sniff the SQL*net traffic from your machine to the db...i'm not in a place to help you with that anymore

Answer (score 1):

Tracing the queries an active software app is running might take a while. As such it might be easier to dig the data out another way:

You want to know which table and column holds some data, like a user first name.

Generate something unique, like a GUID or some impossible name that never occurs in your db (like 'a87d5iw78456w865wd87s7dtjdi') and enter that as the First name using the UI. Save the data

Run this query against oracle:

```
SELECT 
  REPLACE(REPLACE(
    'UNION ALL SELECT ''{t}'', ''{c}'' FROM {t} WHERE {c} = ''a87d5iw78456w865wd87s7dtjdi'' ',
    '{t}', table_name),
    '{c}', column_name
  )  
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE data_type like '%char%'
```

This is "an sql that writes an SQL" - It'll generate a result set that is basically a list of sql statements like this:

```
UNION ALL SELECT 'tablename', 'columnname' FROM tablename WHERE columnname = 'a87d5iw78456w865wd87s7dtjdi'
UNION ALL SELECT 'table2name', 'column2name' FROM table2name WHERE column2name = 'a87d5iw78456w865wd87s7dtjdi'
UNION ALL SELECT 'table3name', 'column3name' FROM table3name WHERE column3name = 'a87d5iw78456w865wd87s7dtjdi'
```

There will be one query for each column in each table in the db. Only CHARacter columns will be searched, by the way

Remove the first `UNION ALL`

Run it and wait a looong time while oracle basically searches every column in every table, in the db, for your weird name.

Eventually it produces an output like:

```
TABLE_NAME        COLUMN_NAME
crm_contacts_info first_name
```

So you know your name `a87d5iw78456w865wd87s7dtjdi` was saved, by the UI, in crm_contacts_info.first_name

Answer (score 1):

> If it is possible, how could i get the session_id from the guy that is
>   using the oracle E-BUSINESS-SUITE Application?

Yes, this is definitely possible. First things first, you need to figure out which schema/username "the guy" is using. If you don't know, you can ask the guy or have him run some simple query (something like `select user from dual;` will work) to get that info.

Once you have the schema name, you can query the `V$SESSION` table to figure out the session id. Have the guy log in, then query the `V$SESSION` table. Your query would look something like this: `select * from v$session where username ='[SCHEMA]';` where `[SCHEMA]` is the schema name that the guy is using to log in. This will give you the SID, serial #, status etc. You will need this info to trace the guy's session.

Generating a trace file for the session is relatively simple. You can start a trace for the entire database, or just for one session. Since you're only interested in the guy's session, you only need to trace that one. To begin the trace, you could use a command that looks something like this: `EXEC DBMS_MONITOR.session_trace_enable(session_id=>[SESSIONID], serial_num=>[SERIAL#]);` where `[SESSIONID]` and `[SERIAL#]` are the numbers you got from the previous step. **Please keep in mind that the guy will need to be logged in for the session trace to give you any results**.

Once the guy is logged in and you have enabled session trace, have the guy run whatever commands from the E-Business suite that you're interested in. Be aware that the more the guy (or the application) does while the trace is enabled, the more information you will have to get through to find whatever it is you're looking for. This can be a TON of data with applications. Just warning you ahead of time.

After the guy is finished doing the tasks, you need to disable the trace. This can be done using the DBMS_MONITOR package like before, only slightly different. The command would look something like this: `EXEC DBMS_MONITOR.session_trace_disable(session_id=>[SESSIONID], serial_num=>[SERIAL#]);` using the same `[SESSIONID]` and `[SERIAL#]` as before.

Assuming everything has been done correctly, this will generate the trace file. The reason why @thatjeffsmith mentioned server access is because you will need to access whatever server(s) the database lives on in order to get the trace file. If you do not have access to the server, you will need to work with a DBA or someone with access in order to get it. If you just need help figuring out where the trace file is, you could run the following query using the `[SESSIONID]` from before:

```
SELECT p.tracefile
FROM   v$session s
       JOIN v$process p ON s.paddr = p.addr
WHERE  s.sid = [SESSIONID];
```

This should return a directory that looks similar to this: `/u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/[database]/[instance]/trace/[instance]_ora_010719.trc`

Simply navigate to that directory, pull the trace file using WinSCP, FileZilla, or the app of your choice, and that should do it.

Good luck, and hope this helps!

Comment: Really nice explanation!
Dude, i dont understand this part: "Yes, this is definitely possible. First things first, you need to figure out which schema "the guy" is using. If you don't know, you can ask the guy or have him run some simple query (something like select user from dual; will work) to get that info." The other guy only has credentials for the oracle e-business-suite application, i think he has no idea what scheme is using and he cannot run any query on the application :/

Comment: If i use this query: select * from v$session where username ='[SCHEMA]' using my own username is does not match anything, why?

Comment: Glad to be of help! While I'm not sure of you're environment, I would bet that the username the other guy is using to sign into the application is the same as his database schema. Just ask him for the username, then query the V$SESSION table and confirm it's him. You could also simply query the 'ALL_USERS' table or just ask someone more familiar with the application for those details. If the select from v$session query is not working, check the case of your username condition. If your username is stored in all caps, your query must match. [SCHEMA] is not the same as [Schema] or [schema].

Comment: If i use this query: select user from dual, it shows me my username.
When i try to execute the other query: select * from v$session where username ='[MYUSERNAME]' it shows empty rows. Why? Have you got any idea?

Comment: There are a few possibilities: 1.) The username/schema ([MYUSERNAME]) does not have any active sessions on the database and you have signed in with a different username/schema. 2.) You are not entering the username/schema correctly. Try the query with your username/schema in ALL CAPS and surrounded by 'single quotes'. 3.) There is some type of weird trigger that prevents error messages from being displayed and instead returns no rows.

Comment: Dude, everytime that i want to execute this query i got this error:
https://imgur.com/a/1qgoJnD or this one: https://imgur.com/a/E8n7nAQ

Comment: The ORA-00933 is a formatting error. It looks like you are using Toad, so whatever you have on lines 1-4 in that screenshot is probably causing that error. As a note, it's always a good idea to end your statements with a semi colon (;). The second screenshot with the ORA-06550 error can mean a couple of things: 1. You do not have the necessary permissions to execute the DBMS_MONITOR package. You need to have the DBA privilege or have "execute on sys.dbms_monitor" explicitly granted to you. Or 2. The DBMS_MONITOR package was dropped/never installed on the database.

Comment: You will need to contact a DBA/admin to have that permission granted to you. If you are the admin, simply sign in with a schema that has the DBA privilege and you should be able to execute that statement. To confirm that the package exists, open Schema Browser in Toad, select "SYS" from the schema list, and select "Packages" from the object list. You should see the DBMS_MONITOR package along side a number of other sys packages that exist in the database.

Comment: i was not able to find any DBMS_MONITOR package.. maybe i have not got the necessary permissions to see it or it has never been installed :(

Comment: Are you able to see any of the DBMS* packages? There are hundreds, so if you aren't able to see any of them, it's probably safe to assume that you have not been granted the necessary permissions. To be 100% certain, contact a DBA or an admin for assistance.

Comment: I can see many packages but not the one you mentioned :/
Okay, im gonna do that!

Answer (score 0):

The SQLs executed from the EBS frontend are usually too fast to be seen in v$session. If a SQL is slower than a second (or if the snapshot timing is right), you would see it in v$active_session_history, which captures a snapshot of all active sessions every second.

The place you should look instead at is v$sqlarea, which can be done by SQL, via Toad using the Database->Monitor->SGA Trace/Optimization menu option or by our Blitz Report https://www.enginatics.com/reports/dba-sga-sql-performance-summary/.

This data however has information on module (i.e. which OAF page, Form, Concurrent etc.) and responsibility (action column) level only and it does not contain session or application user information.

The unique key is sql_id and plan_hash_value, which means that for SQLs executed by different modules and from different responsibilities, only the module executing it first will be shown.

If you sort the data by last_active_time and filter for the module in question, it's almost as good as a trace. Bind values used can be retrieved from v$sql_bind_capture, which above Blitz Report does as well.

Comment: Sounds interesting!
I executed this query: SELECT * FROM   v$active_session_history and there is a column called sql_id and another one called sql_plan_hash_value.
I dont understand how could i get all the queries / tables that were invoked in the application.

Comment: I dont understand this part: "The place you should look instead at is v$sqlarea" what should i do?

Comment: As v$active_session_history doesn't necessarily track all SQLs (might be missing if they are shorter than a second), you can find them in v$sqlarea instead - at least directly after they got executed / before they are aged out. Use the Blitz Report query shown above to get additional EBS module and responsibility information. In v$sqlarea however, the information can no longer be tied to individual sessions or EBS users.